# keras trained model using different tf device

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using a trained model form `keras`. this model doesn't fit in to the GPU memory so I want to divide it into CPU and GPU and maybe on GPUs on different machines.

**1)**    So, if I want to get all `tf.variable` on my CPU and the calculation on GPU how can I do this. Because some articles show that we can place the tf.variable on CPU and the calculation on a GPU. (I am talking about a pre-trained `keras model`).

**2)**    If I want to separate the layers of the pre-trained model  into different GPU on different machines. is it correct to use `with tf.device` and then add the layers to my sequence model like this.

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
cnnModel = Sequential()

for layer in vgg16_model.layers[0:13]:
    cnnModel.add(layer)
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[14:16]:
    cnnModel.add(layer)
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[17:21]:
    cnnModel.add(layer)

with tf.device(........):
   cnnModel.add(Dense(2048, name="compress_1"))
   cnnModel.add(Dense(1024, name="compress_2"))
   cnnModel.add(Dense(512, name="compress_3"))

with tf.device(........):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(cnnModel,input_shape=(10,224,224,3),name="CNN_Model"))

with tf.device(........):
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(256,name="lstm1",return_sequences=True))
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128,name="lstm2",return_sequences=True))
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(528))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(39,activation='sigmoid'))
```

Thank you very much.

**Update**
I was thinking if I can access the attribute `variable_device` in the tensor variables of the model and set it by my self to the CPU.

btw I am using the tf.keras implementation.

**Update2**
I have tried some In the tensorboard I can see this:
[image][image]

[image]

Does this mean that the calculation and the training is in the CPU and the data is in the GPU??

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the way to do it.

Pay attention because copying variables between CPU and GPU and other machines takes time. You might get more performance ignoring the GPU, using a single machine, or only syncing the variables between machines after a number of batches have been completed (Async SGD).

Comment: I really need to do this because the network has  129.000.000 parameters and it can't fit in the gpu`4GO` memory. What I had proposed like a code is for sharing weights and calculation. if I want to only have the weights in the CPU and the calculation on a `GPU` how could I do this with a trained`keras model?

Comment: if I am using a non trained NN I only need to declare the `tf.variable` in `tf.device(cpu)`  but I don't know how to access this variables inside a trained model

Comment: There are two components to a saved model, the graph and the session. The graph holds the nodes/operations that you want to do. The session stores the values of the variables you have. Normally a model export clears the device placement so when you import it the machine where it runs can figure out what works (in case you don't have a GPU). You can redefine the graph like you mentioned to place the variables on the CPU, then load the session of the pre-trained model to get the values of the variables.

Comment: Can you please explain more the solution in you answer. thx for the help. I really appreciated

Comment: I didn't figure out how do it should use `with cpu` when importing the model like this: `vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
`